# Python - Encoding Genomic Data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

Hi I'm trying to encode a Genome, stored as a string inside a dataframe read from a CSV.

Right now I'm looking to split each string in the dataframe under the column 'Genome' into a list of it's base pairs i.e. from ('acgt...') to ('a','c','g','t'...) then convert each base pair into a float (0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00) respectively.

I thought I was looking for a split function to split each string into characters but none seem to work on the data in the dataframe even when transformed to string using `.tostring`

Here's my most recent code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


def string_to_array(my_string):
    my_string = my_string.lower()
    my_string = re.sub('[^acgt]', 'z', my_string)
    my_array = np.array(list(my_string))
    return my_array

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(np.array(['a','g','c','t','z']))

def ordinal_encoder(my_array):
    integer_encoded = label_encoder.transform(my_array)
    float_encoded = integer_encoded.astype(float)
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 0] = 0.25  # A
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 1] = 0.50  # C
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 2] = 0.75  # G
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 3] = 1.00  # T
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 4] = 0.00  # anything else, z
    return float_encoded



dfpath = 'C:\\Users\\CAAVR\\Desktop\\Ison.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(dfpath)

df = ordinal_encoder(string_to_array(dataframe[['Genome']].values.tostring()))
print(df)
```

I've tried making my own function but I don't have any clue how they work. Everything I try points to not being able to process data when it's in a numpy array and nothing is working to transform the data to another type.

Thanks for the tips!

Edit: Here is the print of the dataframe-

```
 Antibiotic  ...                                             Genome
0       isoniazid  ...  ccctgacacatcacggcgcctgaccgacgagcagaagatccagctc...
1       isoniazid  ...  gggggtgctggcggggccggcgccgataaccccaccggcatcggcg...
2       isoniazid  ...  aatcacaccccgcgcgattgctagcatcctcggacacactgcacgc...
3       isoniazid  ...  gttgttgttgccgagattcgcaatgcccaggttgttgttgccgaga...
4       isoniazid  ...  ttgaccgatgaccccggttcaggcttcaccacagtgtggaacgcgg...
```

There are 5 columns 'Genome' being the 5th in the list I don't know why 1. `.head()` will not work and 2. why `print()` doesn't give me all columns...

Comment: Could you post a short, representative piece of your dataframe? Best would be the output of `df.head()` or `df.head().to_dict()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `LabelEncoder` is what you want. This is a simple transformation, I recommend doing it directly. Start with a lookup your base pair mapping:

```py
lookup = {
  'a': 0.25,
  'g': 0.50,
  'c': 0.75,
  't': 1.00
  # z: 0.00
}
```

Then apply the lookup to value of the "Genome" column. The `values` attribute will return the resulting dataframe as an `ndarray`.

```py
dataframe['Genome'].apply(lambda bps: pd.Series([lookup[bp] if bp in lookup else 0.0 for bp in bps.lower()])).values
```

Comment: Ran this and got:     valid = (locs % step == 0) & (locs >= 0) & (target_array < stop)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (32766,) and data type int64

Comment: Your machine doesn't have enough memory to create the array that you want to create. Find a larger machine or try to solve a smaller problem.

Comment: The transformation doesn't use much memory until the very end. I have already validated that no other null values exist so would omitting the  "else 0.0 for bp" free up that memory needed for the rest of the transformation?

Comment: No, that would not have an impact. How long are the base pair strings (i.e. how many base pairs)? How many rows do you have? Why do you want to code them as floats?

Comment: The strings are whole genome sequences, I want to convert them to floats to run the entire sequence through a neural network. Would a method of one hot encoding character by character run more efficient?

Comment: Definitely not! To determine the memory requirements, you need to know how long the strings are and how many rows the dataset has.

Comment: I believe the strings should be around 4.5 million base pairs long and about 80,000 in the dataset. Honestly thought this machine had more memory than it does. Anyway to process over these in batches and not all at once?

Comment: An array 4.5M by 80k with a 64 bit datatype will be ~3TB in memory. I suggest you take a step back, think about what you're doing and why.

Comment: I fed this function through a chunk function and it worked thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it worked for you, please accept the answer.